# file_get_contents - getting real complete HTTP answer (not just headers)

Tags: php, http

I'm trying to get full HTTP answer over a call to **file_get_contents** function. I'm doing an **HTTP POST** call, putting credentials to login to my website, process some work, then return a HTTP answer to the caller.
When credentials are not good, i send a **HTTP 403** return code, with a message as follow (Raw HTTP response as shown in **SoapUI**) :

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 09:02:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 515
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 09:02:13 GMT

L'authentification user/password n'est pas autorisée pour le login 'sebastien' depuis l'adresse '127.0.0.1'.
```

How can i get the message at bottom after calling file_get_contents in php ? Message is not in the headers, so **$http_response_header won't work**. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: "Server: Apache-Coyote....X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge" - something very odd here.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [HTTP stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to use with file_get_contents() then call [stream_get_meta_data()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) but personally I would just use Curl with [CURLOPT_HEADER=true](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Note that since the service is returning a 403 rather than a 401, then you're going to need cookies (if it is possible at all) to authenticate. For that you will need Curl.

Comment: Yes. Use Curl. Or better yet, use Guzzle. Curl can be a bit of a pain, but Guzzle makes it easy (almost as easy as just using `file_get_contents()`). Also note that PHP can be configured to prevent `file_get_contents()` from working over http; if you intend your code to run on systems where you don't control the system config, then you must use Curl or Guzzle instead.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP response body should be separated from headers by an empty line: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

Then the body should be available as a result of `file_get_contents` call.

Comment: Well the body is separated from the headers (it wasn't showing properly on my first post, i edited it), but since the HTTP response code is 403, the body is not returned by file_get_contents, which is a boolean (false) and not a string in this case.

Answer (score 0):

the HTTP context option [ignore_errors](https://www.php.net/context.http#context.http.ignore-errors) is needed to get the content body of the page when an HTTP error code (4XX or 5XX) is returned.